# HTML5 audio player in Firefox is not working

Tags: html, firefox, html5-audio

HTML5 audio player in Firefox 53.0.2 (64-bit) is not playing audio file with 
bitrate 23 kbps but it is working fine in chrome.

download file here:https://www.sendspace.com/file/qf23ca

**Audio file details :**

```
codec: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3)
channels : mono
container: wav
Bitrate: 23 kbps
sample rate: 22050 Hz
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe because "Le corbeau" put fire on the fox ? I can repro, indeed it doesn't like this codec. Can't you just reencode it in a more broad way (here your mp3 codec returns `mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055)` in ffmpeg, I'm not quite sure what it means, but it doesn't sound normal.) Ah, in Nightly I've got this report when loaded from my localhost : `NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_METADATA_ERR (0x806e0006)` but it does work from your link...

Comment: Are you able to run it in html now in firefox?

Comment: Only from [direct link](https://apps.learningbranch.com/thoojaQARest/thoojaQA/data/activityItemData/592d0d3e65fb320c776ac416/592d0d0d65fb320c776ac305?nocache=1496124734831)... That's weird. Something in the request might break it...

Comment: I took the liberty to copy your file on my dropbox If you mind or don't own the rights for this file, please let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: direct link works fine but in audio tag html5 it is not working in firefox only works in chrome. here is the file you can download it https://www.sendspace.com/file/qf23ca

Comment: I posted an answer with a workaround and an link to [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=guided#h=dupes|Core|Audio%2FVideo%3A%20Playback) where you should tell them about this issue.

Answer (score 4):

This is a really weird bug :

Firefox **is** able to read this file, but only if the document points directly to it...

You should definitely report this to [BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=guided#h=dupes%7CCore%7CAudio%2FVideo%3A%20Playback).

For a workaround, you can use an `<embed>`, `<iframe>` or `<object>` directly pointing to this file :

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = e => 
document.querySelectorAll('object,iframe,embed,audio')
.forEach(e=>{
e.src = e.data = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/v4laq04yl1gmcef/592d0d0d65fb320c776ac305.mp3?dl=0";
if(e.play)e.play()
});
```

```css
object,iframe,embed,audio{
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<button>Set srcs</button><br>

<p>Audio fails<audio controls></audio> </p>
<p>embeddeds work
<object data=""></object>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
<embed src="">
</p>
```

---

#### [edit]

Here is an ugly workaround implementation that will enable to have the `<audio>` element inside the main document, still playing.

NOTE : This hack will work only with same-origin data, or cross-origin accessible ones.

```js
// we've got a problem, probably FF
function uglyFFworkaround() {
  const frame = document.createElement('iframe'); // create an iframe

  frame.onload = e => {
    const doc = frame.contentDocument;
    // grab the mediaElement (usually an <video>)
    const inner_aud = doc.querySelectorAll('audio,video')[0];
    var new_aud = doc.createElement('audio'); // create an new audio from our frame's document
    new_aud.src = inner_aud.currentSrc; // set its src to the one of the default video
    inner_aud.pause(); // pause the video
    new_aud.controls = true;
    frame.replaceWith(new_aud); // replace the frame with the audio element
    aud = new_aud; // update our variable to point to this new audio
    aud.play(); // start playing
  };

  // in case our document is not on the same origin as the media
  fetch(aud.src) // fetch the resource
    .then(r => r.blob()) // as a blob
    .then(b => { // so that we can access the frame's document
      // ( if it were on the same origin, we could avoid this fetch altogether )
      frame.src = URL.createObjectURL(b);
      aud.replaceWith(frame);
    });
}
```

And you can call it either from `play().catch()`, or from the onerror event.

**[Live Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6t2ax0r2/)** since stacksnippet's don't allow accessing nested iframe's docs :